# Minecraft, sprint key

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Every minute or two when playing a game on a server, I randomly stop sprinting and I have to double tap <kbd>w</kbd> to start sprinting again. I was just wondering if there was a way to stop this issue from occurring?

Comment: You can bind a separate key that you can hold to sprint.

Answer (score 2):

As other answers have stated, by simply pressing the <kbd>L-CTRL</kbd> you can start sprinting without having to worry about the awkward "double-w" key function.

As for *why* this is happening, it's a likely possibility that there is an occasional latency between server and client, which causes a loss of input, and therefore, you stop sprinting. Unfortunately, there isn't too much that can be done about this, especially if you're not the only one experiencing this.

However, if you can boost the speed of your network in any way, this may help - switch from Wi-Fi to Ethernet, or perhaps upgrade your network plan.

Comment: I believe that this is actually a feature.  if you press sprint then it ends after 30 seconds, if you hold sprint its indefinite. as per https//minecraft.gamepedia.com/Sprinting (note 1 is helpful in this context)

Comment: I have never experienced this

Answer (score 0):

About 4 years ago, a key for sprinting was added. By default it's <kbd>Left Ctrl</kbd>. You don't need to hold it, because when you press it, you will be sprinting until you either stop walking forwards or you walk against a wall, but you can hold it, that way you'll start sprinting again when you start walking again or get away from the wall.

Comment: Sprinting also stops after 30 seconds if you don't hold the sprint key, to simulate 'exhaustion'. see [this](https://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Sprinting#Usage) webpage